# copying contents of file to another file n bytes at a time in c

Tags: c, file, unix

Trying to copy the contents of a file to another file by copying n bytes at a time in c. I believe the code below works for copying one byte at a time but am not sure how to make it work for n number of bytes, have tried making a character array of size n and changing the read/write functions to `read(sourceFile , &c, n)` and `write(destFile , &c, n)`, but the buffer doesn't appear to work that way.

```
#include <fcntl.h>    
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

void File_Copy(int sourceFile, int destFile, int n){
    char c;

    while(read(sourceFile , &c, 1) != 0){
        write(destFile , &c, 1);
    }


}

int main(){
    int fd, fd_destination;      
    fd = open("source_file.txt", O_RDONLY); //opening files to be read/created and written to
    fd_destination = open("destination_file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT); 

    clock_t begin = clock(); //starting clock to time the copying function

    File_Copy(fd, fd_destination, 100); //copy function

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; //timing display

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `read()` returns the number of bytes read. That's important to know when you want to do something with those bytes.

Comment: `while(read(sourceFile , &c, 1) != 0)` -> `while(read(sourceFile , &c, 1) == 1)`

Comment: What does "but the buffer doesn't appear to work that way." mean? In which way did your attempt fail?

Comment: You should check manpage of `read` in which cases the function can return a value less than the expected number.

Answer (score 1):

> how to make it work for n number of bytes

Just read N number of bytes and copy that many bytes that you successfully read.

```
#define N  4096 
void File_Copy(int sourceFile, int destFile, int n){
    char c[N];
    const size_t csize = sizeof(c)/sizeof(*c);
    while (1) {
        const ssize_t readed = read(sourceFile, c, csize);
        if (readed <= 0) {
            // nothing more to read
            break;
        }
        // copy to destination that many bytes we read
        const ssize_t written = write(destFile, c, readed);
        if (written != readed) {
            // we didn't transfer everything and destFile should be blocking
            // handle error
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that c[N] is stored on the stack. On my system the stack size is 8MB. You might want to use malloc...

Comment: With `N = 4096`, that's 4kilobytes. So it will be using 0.0005% of your stack space.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy a buffer of size `n` at once:

```
void File_Copy(int sourceFile, int destFile, int n){
    char c[n];

    ssize_t st;
    while((st = read(sourceFile , c, n)) > 0){
        write(destFile , c, st);
    }
}
```

Note, that not necessarily `n` bytes are always copied at once, it might be less. And you also have to check the return value of `write()` and handle the situation, when less bytes were written, as it fits your needs.

One example is a loop:

```
while (st > 0) {
    int w = write(destFile, c, st);
    if (w < 0) {
        perror("write");
        return;
    }
    st -= w;
}
```

Another issue: When you create the destination file here

```
fd_destination = open("destination_file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
```

you do not specify the third *mode* parameter. This leads to a random mode, which might lead to this `open()` to fail the next time. So better add a valid mode, for example like this:

```
fd_destination = open("destination_file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
```

This might have distorted your test results.

Comment: `write` may write less than `st`, it needs a loop.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I already mention that this has to be handled. A loop is one possibility.

Comment: Alright I can understand most of whats going on here, but what I don't understand is why the number of bytes in the buffer seems to not effect performance at all. No matter how high/low I make n it seems to not change the time it takes to perform the copy, is there a reason for that? I would assume that changing the amount of bits to be copied at once would have some measurable affect on the runtime.

Comment: @Wizlawn Yes, it should. You probably test it with too small files, what are your total runtimes?

Comment: @Ctx I have been getting around 10-11 seconds. The time seems to mostly be random, no correlation to the n value I give, and I have tested values 1 up to 10000.

Comment: @Wizlawn Can you try and _delete_ the destination file before each attempt?

Comment: @Wizlawn I addressed another issue in the answer now, which might be responsible for your test results.

Comment: I have been deleting the file every time between attempts. I added that line to the code and it still seems to be random, putting n=1000 took 10 seconds 790 milliseconds and n=1 took 10 seconds 690 milliseconds.

Comment: @Wizlawn You are doing something wrong here... I have tried it with a 10MB file, with 1 byte blocksize it tages 8.5 seconds, with 100 bytes blocksize it takes 0.1 seconds. How big is your file?

Comment: My file is 6.3MB

Comment: @Wizlawn Then I would say that you copy with 1 byte blocksize both times. Did you recompile after changing the value? Can you run the command with `strace` to see, if really a 10000 byte blocksize is used?

Comment: @Ctx Ok I did some error checking and it was just user error, it does work perfectly and when I use the strace I get the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version using *lseek* (no loop required):
It relies on read and write always processing the complete buffer and never a part of it (I don't know if this is guaranteed).

```
void File_Copy(int sourceFile, int destFile)
{
    off_t s = lseek(sourceFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    lseek(sourceFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char* c = malloc(s);

    if (read(sourceFile, c, s) == s)
        write(destFile, c, s);

    free(c);
}
```

The following code does not rely on this assumption and can also be used for file descriptors not supporting *lseek*.

```
void File_Copy(int sourceFile, int destFile, int n)
{
    char* c = malloc(n);
    while (1)
    {
        ssize_t readStatus = read(sourceFile, c, n);
        if (readStatus == -1)
        {
            printf("error, read returned -1, errno: %d\n", errno);
            return;
        }
        if (readStatus == 0)
            break; // EOF

        ssize_t bytesWritten = 0;
        while (bytesWritten != readStatus)
        {
            ssize_t writeStatus = write(destFile, c + bytesWritten, readStatus - bytesWritten);
            if (writeStatus == -1)
            {
                printf("error, write returned -1, errno is %d\n", errno);
                return;
            }
            bytesWritten += writeStatus;
            if (bytesWritten > readStatus) // should not be possible
            {
                printf("how did 'bytesWritten > readStatus' happen?");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    free(c);
}
```

On my system (PCIe SSD) I get best performance with a buffer between 1MB and 4MB (you can also use dd to find this size). Bigger buffers don't make sense. And you need big files (try 50GB) to see the effect.

Comment: And if `sourcefile` isn't seekable?  This can't copy from `stdin` or a socket, for example.

Comment: I did not know that you want a solution that can handle any type of file descriptor.